# ~/.vim folder has gone after vim reinstall (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: vim, ubuntu, vimrc

I had a problem with an arrow keys in Ubuntu (known as the A B C D problem). All advices I have found does not help me to resolve this bug. So, I deside to reinstall vim totaly. After I install it with «sudo apt-get install vim», it's doesn't create .vim folder & .vimrc file in my home… So when I install Akita set of addons it's does not work and my vim runs totaly clear without any highlighting and so on…

How to fix this bug. Where could be .vim && .vimrc folders and files?

Comment: Post to askubuntu.com - the sister-site for Ubuntu.

Comment: keep backup, you must.

Answer (score 0):

The global vim configuration file is at `/etc/vimrc`, local, if it has been created, is hidden in your home folder (`~/.vimrc`). Article [open vimrc file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file)